# Cannot find the LogCat Outputs in Android Source Codes

Tags: android, android-source, android-logcat

I am trying to find the source codes of Android (media) libraries that produce the following the log outputs in LogCat, but cannot find them anywhere. I looked at the source files at: android.googlesource.com and androidxref.com, but either I am missing something essential or the logs are coming from somewhere else...

```
04-07 23:49:33.582: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(8055): ChromiumHTTPDataSource jni::getJavaVM()
04-07 23:49:34.742: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): mDisconnectAtHighwatermark = 0, cacheConfig is NULL(1)
04-07 23:49:34.747: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:36.477: D/HTTPBase(8055): [1] Network BandWidth = 0 Kbps
04-07 23:49:36.477: D/NuCachedSource2(8055): Remaining (64K), HighWaterThreshold (20480)
04-07 23:49:36.477: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:36.477: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(8055): mContentSize is undefined or network might be disconnected
04-07 23:49:36.477: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(8055): mContentSize is undefined or network might be disconnected
04-07 23:49:36.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:38.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:38.502: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:38.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:40.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:40.502: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:40.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:42.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:42.502: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:42.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:44.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:44.502: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:44.502: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:46.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:46.507: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:46.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:48.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:48.507: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:48.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:50.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:50.507: E/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt:Timeout ( player case )
04-07 23:49:50.507: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
04-07 23:49:52.447: D/HTTPBase(8055): [2] Network BandWidth = 59 Kbps
04-07 23:49:52.447: D/NuCachedSource2(8055): Remaining (127K), HighWaterThreshold (20480)
04-07 23:49:52.447: D/NuCachedSource2(8055): readInternal - late!!!
04-07 23:49:52.447: I/NuCachedSource2(8055): readAt: waiting end ( player case )
04-07 23:49:52.447: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(8055): mContentSize is undefined or network might be disconnected
04-07 23:49:52.447: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(8055): mContentSize is undefined or network might be disconnected
04-07 23:49:52.452: D/StreamPlayerService(8055): MIME TYPE: audio/mpeg
04-07 23:49:52.452: I/ACodec(8055):  [] Now uninitialized
04-07 23:49:52.452: I/OMXClient(8055): Using client-side OMX mux.
04-07 23:49:52.457: I/ACodec(8055): [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Loaded
04-07 23:49:52.457: I/ACodec(8055): [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Loaded->Idle
04-07 23:49:52.462: I/ACodec(8055): [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Idle->Executing
04-07 23:49:52.467: I/ACodec(8055): [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Executing
04-07 23:49:52.472: D/StreamPlayerService(8055): Output format has changed to {sample-rate=22050, channel-count=2, what=1869968451, mime=audio/raw}
```

Comment: What is source of these logcat messages? Device and version of Android?

Comment: The device is a Samsung Note 3 (SM-N9000Q), and the Android version is 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the goal of finding source files, but source file for `NuCachedSource2` can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/jb-mr1-release/media/libstagefright/NuCachedSource2.cpp)

Comment: Thanks, but it was not what I was looking for. That file does not contain the log output messages. I looked at the includes, also... I'd like to know who's producing those outputs...

Comment: For instance, mIsMetadataRetriever. I could not find this variable in any source codes... ?

Comment: @burakk can't find that on AOSP. Are you using custom ROM?

Comment: The device is a Samsung Note 3 (SM-N9000Q), and the Android version is 4.4.2. The carrier is Turkcell from Turkey.